# Транспортная задача

Tags: алгоритм, график

Добрый день, буду рад любым наводкам

Есть такая задача.

Желтые круги – это стоянки.
Зеленые квадраты – это склады(Цифра внутри квадрата – это кол-во товара, которое есть на складе).
Синие круги – это магазины.
Стрелочки – это дороги(Цифра в стрелочках – длина/вес)

Допустим есть заявка от магазина привезти ему 20шт. товара.

Необходимо выбрать с какой стоянки взять грузовик и на какие склады заехать, чтобы набрать данные 20 штук товара, чтобы путь грузовика был оптимальный с наименьшим суммарным весом.
Каждую точку можно посещать сколько угодно раз.

Какой алгоритм или совокупность алгоритмов лучше использовать в случаях(когда данный граф ориентированный(у дорог есть направление и стоимость может отличаться) или же когда граф неориентированный(т.е. точки связаны каким-то среднеарифметическим весом)?

[image: ориентировочный граф]

Пока была идея взять магазины и только склады. Методом потенциалов(вроде классическая транспортная задача)  найти сперва какие склады удовлетворяют потребностям магазина(т.е. на них есть кол-во нужного товара и путь от склада оптимальный). Затем найти с какой стоянки кратчайший путь до магазина через данные выбранные склады(последовательность заездов на склады не оговорена), правда не совсем понятно какой алгоритм лучше для этой части. Но думал либо использовать А* только искать до тех пор пока в маршруте не будут содержаться нужные склады, либо Дейкстру только k! перестановок(задание очереди посещений складов).

Но первая проблема, выбор складов не оптимальный в том плане, если я правильно понял метод потенциалов, оцениваются только кол-во товара и цена/вес ребра от склада до магазина с учетом, что доставка будет непосредственно от склада. А в моем случае грузовик 1 и посещает он склады последовательно, т.е. есть шанс неправильно выбрать пару складов.

Думал может опять же попробовать использовать A* и искать до тех пор пока не найду решение, кратчайший путь через склады на которых в сумме достаточно товара, прогонять для каждой стоянки и выбирать оптимальный вариант.

Но тут есть тоже небольшая проблема, что делать если 2 магазина одновременно дадут две заявки. Это тогда нужно будет для каждого магазина и стоянки его прогонять, а затем из множества решений  выбирать – боюсь долго будет. Вершин графа планируется не много, может максимум 20.

Comment: Думаю нужно четко понимать - эта задача теоретическая или все происходит в реальной жизни ? Потому что в реальной жизни посетить два и более складов ради более короткого маршрута - выглядит нелепо (и никто так ездить не будет)

Comment: Также определитесь с критерием динамичности. Одновременно (с точностью до наносекунды) ничего не случается. В каком диапазоне от выдачи задания до его перерасчета вы можете менять маршруты/задания (5 минут, час) и передавать агентам изменения. И второе - будете ли вы рассчитывать на агентов почти выполнивших свои задания (если ему до склада 2 минуты, а ближайшему свободному агенту - 35).

Comment: Тогда считайте теоритическая) Ну допустим есть смысл оценивать задания на два часа вперед и прогнозировать на это время.